# Service Fabric web api returning Error Message: Invalid argument, Code: E_INVALIDARG

Tags: api, azure-service-fabric, stateful, invalid-argument

I have deployed my service fabric stateful api created using default Dotnet framework template in the azure cluster. When I tried to access the api getting below error.
{"Error":{"Code":"E_INVALIDARG","Message":"Invalid argument"}}

However this working fine in my local cluster.
below my api url 
https://svfab03test.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/891d72b6-06cd-4dbf-a6b8-8ee1f4382045/131818608371580228/23f6df71-2458-4e5e-bdfd-76ba47ea8f46/api/values

I have tried like this also but getting the same error
https://svfab03test.centralus.cloudapp.azure.com:19080/PublishTestSF/PublishTestAPI/api/values

Can someone please help

Comment: I have tried 19080 and end point port. Also the GUIDs are as part of the endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have changed the defaults configuration, *Service Fabric Reverse Proxy* by default runs on **port 19081**, not *19080*, the port 19080 is used by the gateway to 
 provide to access service fabric explorer.

You should try:  `https://domain:19081/appName/servicename/apipath`

if they are stateful, you should pass `?PartitionKey=<key>&PartitionKind=<partitionkind>`

Please see the docs in here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reverseproxy